# PHP password protect a link attached to an image

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, passwords, password-protection

Herroo everyone!
I am building a website for my dad. He is an accountant. We have Google calendars setup for him to take appointments. The website is just a pretty front page with three clickable images that link to different calenders. Two of the buttons are linked to employee calendars and are not password protected which is fine. We want new people to be able to sign up for them. My dad however is overbooked and needs his link password protected so he can give the password out to specific clients in order for them to make their appointments. He does not want see new people.

I can work with html and css but a total newb to PHP/MYSQL. I have been doing a lot of research and downloaded many tutorials/sample codes the past few days but I am still confused. This is what I've gotten so far after modifying some sample code. I set the password to be barney and do not require a user name and saved it as php1.php in a sub folder called protect. I remember reading somewhere that this well help with people bypassing the password.

```
  <?php
$password = "barney";

if (md5($_POST['txtPassword']) != $password) {
?>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">


        <p><label for="txtpassword">Password:</label>
    <br /><input type="password" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" /></p>


    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></p>
</form>
<?php
}
```

after this I am stuck... I do not know how to apply this to my html page and attach it to the image/link. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Are you sure you created a database to store the passwords?

Comment: no I am totally new to this and unsure of pretty much everything lol. I figured this would be a great learning experience to php/mysql. If you could point me in the right direction I can post back with what I can figure out! :D

Comment: You can check this out for a start: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-login-system-for-a-simple-website/
You can show the desired link for calender once you are done with authentication.

Comment: You should create a database for storing the user details.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem here is that you are comparing your password `$password` to an `md5` version of the submitted password. They will be different and so you will always be shown the login form.

Replace with

```
<?php
$password = "barney";

if ($_POST['txtPassword'] != $password) {
    ?>Login form here<?php
} else {
     ?>Restricted access here<?php
}
```

But then you should keep in mind that such a scheme remains bad practice and low-security:

- the password is stored in plain-text
- you don't check how many
  attempts a user makes to retrieve the password (see brute-force
  attacks)
  ...

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the PHP file you could always modify the .htaccess file if it is available to you.

here is a quick how-to:
http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

here is more detailed info:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml